# A set of duplicated normal random variables

Tags: distributions

I am working on the following problem. 
I have a set of $n$ random variables $$X=\{x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}\} \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$$I also have a set of $n$ random variables $$Y=\{p_{1},p_{2},...,p_{n}\} \sim U(a,b)$$ Using these two sets of random variables, I create a set $Z$. $$Z=\{x_{1},...,x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{2},...,x_{n},...,x_{n}\}$$ Note that I listed $x_{i}$ for $p_{i}$ times ($i=1,2,...n$). I would like to know how to evalueate this set of variables. For example, how can I get an expression for the average of its components?

Comment: You will need some kind of generalization of the definition of "random variable" to make sense of $Z.$  It doesn't fit the usual definition because it has a variable (and random) number of components.  Along with a definition you will need to explain what the mean and variance of such a mathematical object might be.  Are you sure you have correctly articulated your problem?

Comment: @whuber Thank you very much for your comment. I am sure I have correctly articulated my problem. As you pointed out, it seems difficult to define the mean and variance in this case. What I'd like to know here is whether I can somehow evaluate the distribution of Z. For example, can the average value of all the elements in Z upper-bounded? Or, does the distribution curve still look like Bell-shape? Since I am a beginner of statistics, I have no idea how to generalize the concept of random variables in this case...

Comment: $Z$ does not have a distribution.  If you think it does, could you supply your definition?  On the other hand, certain *functions* of $Z,$ such as the average of its components, *are* random variables in the ordinary sense.  I suspect you might be interested in such functions rather than in $Z$ itself.  But which ones?

Comment: @whuber You are absolutely right! What I am interested in are functions of $Z$ rather than its "distribution". Thank you for your clear feedback. I will modify my question.

Comment: Re the edit: the average of the components of $Z$ can be expressed as $$\bar Z = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n p_i X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n p_i}.$$ This is not easy to analyze; except in very limited situations (such as $a=b$ or $n=1$) I doubt there is any closed form expression for most of its properties (such as the mean and variance).

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your reply. I will update my question once I figure out what kind of properties I want to know. (There may be no closed-form solutions for them, though)

Comment: Is U discrete uniform? If so, you may have a 'random sum of random variables'  in the numerator (google it). There are formulas for mean and variance of numerator. Also relatively easy to simulate results for cases where $\mu, \sigma, a, b$ are known.

Comment: @BruceET Yes, U is a discrete uniform. So, following your advice, it seems that I can get the mean and variance of the numerator. Thank you for your help.